# Mongoose not saving all documents in loop

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

So I have the following code in an Express app for the POST api:

```
var dashSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  key: 'string',
  status: 'string',
  assignee: 'string',
  summary: 'string'
});

var dashData = mongoose.model('dashData', dashSchema);


app.post('/api/data', function(req, res) {
  var issues = req.body.issues;

  for (var i=0;i<issues.length;i++) {
    dashData.create({key: issues[i].key, status: issues[i].fields.status.name, assignee: issues[i].fields.assignee, summary: issues[i].fields.summary});
  }

  res.end();
  });
```

Whenever I post an array of 5 "issues" only the first two are being written to the MongoDB. I assume this is because that is all it can write in the time it takes to iterate through the loop, but I don't know how to make it write all of the data, and then return the response.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

In Mongoose, `.create` returns a promise. Install a promise library like `bluebird` to give you access to `Promise.all` and you can do this:

```
var Promise = require('bluebird'); // could also be Q or another A+ library

app.post('/api/data', function(req, res, next) {
  var issues = req.body.issues;

  // map the issues to an array of promises for created dashData docs
  var createdPromises = issues.map(function(issue){
    return dashData.create({key: issue.key, status: issue.fields.status.name, assignee: issue.fields.assignee, summary: issue.fields.summary}); // returns a promise
  });

  Promise.all(createdPromises).then(function(results){
    res.json(results); // only sends when all docs have been created
  }).then(null, next); // error handler - pass to `next`

});
```

Comment: BTW — since this post's publication in 2015, native `Promise.all` support via ES2015 code has become widespread, so you often don't *have* to install a promise library (depending on your environment, supported platforms etc.).

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be to end the response when the last iteration is reached:

```
  for (var i=0;i<issues.length;i++) {
    dashData.create({key: issues[i].key, status: issues[i].fields.status.name, assignee: issues[i].fields.assignee, summary: issues[i].fields.summary});
    if(i === issues.length - 1) return res.end();
  }
```

Alternatively, you can use the [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) module for more functionality, especially if you need to wait for all the queries to complete.

**Update**

As [Gabriel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4876305/gabriel-lebec) rightly pointed out, the above code doesn't ensure that the queries will finish executing before the response is sent. I think I had mentioned that you should use async `especially if you need to wait for all the queries to complete`. Anyway, if you wish to go without the overhead of async or Promises anyway, you can do something like:

```
  var ctr = 0;
  issues.forEach(function(issue){
        dashData.create({key: issue.key, status: issue.fields.status.name, assignee: issue.fields.assignee, summary: issue.fields.summary}, function(err, doc){
            if (err) { return errorHandler(err); }
            ctr++;
            if (ctr === issues.length) return res.end();
        });
  });
```

Comment: Just because the last `create` has run doesn't mean all prior `create`s have saved. They're async. You need to check that ALL of them are done, using an async tool of some kind (async.js, promises).

Comment: I know, good sir. The OP hasn't handled any query results anyway, just initiated them. At least in this context, he's clearly concerned about the execution, not the errors. As far as the context of his query is concerned, my solution suffices. But to please thy kind eyes,  I shall update my answer.

Comment: Nice raw solution to the async.