# NodeJS async for each object in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, async.js

My problem is that i've got 1 array with multiple objects.
And i need to do stuff for all those single objects in that array.
Async

But it doesn't work?

Code:

```js
console.log('Data: ' + data);

async.eachSeries(data, function (item, callback3) {
 console.log(item.id);
 callback3('0');
}, function done(err) {
 console.log('done');
});
```

And this is what the server loggs:

```
[root@bravo servers]# node app.js
[ { id: 1,
    ownerid: 11,
    topicid: 1,
    content: 'First comment',
    date: Sun Jun 21 2015 23:18:05 GMT+0200 (CEST) },
  { id: 2,
    ownerid: 11,
    topicid: 1,
    content: 'Another test',
    date: Mon Jun 22 2015 00:18:34 GMT+0200 (CEST) } ]
1
done
```

As you can see it's not doing the second one its right going to the done function?

Comment: Why are you using async.js when you don't have anything asynchronous to do? Use a plain loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first argument to your inner callback is non-null (i.e. `'0'`) which is interpreted as an error, leading the function to terminate after the first element is processed. Just make that `callback3(null, '0')`.

For almost all callbacks in Node, the first parameter is usually an `error` object. (I can't think of an exception at the moment, but let's stick to "almost" anyway.)

Hope that solves your problem.

Additionally, if you're using `async` just for a few functions, you should probably avoid it (e.g. by doing [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31191835/1100528)). I've had trouble with large arrays while using `async`. This doesn't relate to your original question; just a suggestion.

Comment: Glad it did. If you're inclined to do that, use `0`, not `'0'`.

Comment: i usally do but on this time when i put 0 in it it gave undefined as an error which he send back and shows on the website. my script only knows when the response obj is 0 that he doesn't have to show anything so i tried '0' but yeah its fixed now thanks!